# MySQL Workbench encoding errors when importing from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, utf

I'm trying to use a csv file (utf-8) to insert some data in a table (utf8mb3, tryed also with utf8mb4). The thing is:

There is a csv line that looks like this:

```
8,raikkonen,7.0,RAI,Kimi,Räikkönen,1979-10-17,Finnish,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimi_R%C3%A4ikk%C3%B6nen
```

But looks like this when inserted into the database:

```
'8', 'raikkonen', '7', 'RAI', 'Kimi', 'RÃ¤ikkÃ¶nen', '1979-10-17', 'Finnish', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimi_R%C3%A4ikk%C3%B6nen'
```

As you can see, there are some encoding errors once data is inserted.

I`ve tryed to solve it using several types of enconding in MySQL workbench, but nothing worked. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: MySQL Workbench has an unfixed bug that matches the issue you describe: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95700 I never use MySQL Workbench because of its many bugs.

Comment: @BillKarwin That seems to be a different symptom, it gets an error rather than import the file.

Comment: As @BillKarwin said, looks like a Workbench bug. I just did again the import from the command line and worked properly.

Comment: Use not importing wizard but LOAD DATA statement, and specify ALL needed importing options. Also check that your table settings allows to receive the data correctly.